# PHP dynamically creating associative array from XML

Tags: php, arrays, loops, dynamic, associative

So I have this XML that I'm strolling through and I'm able to move through it fine. What I want to dynamically create is an associative array in this way:

```
$keyName => $valName
```

Here's how the XML looks like:

```
<dict>
    <key>Major Version</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Minor Version</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Application Version</key><string>7.6.1</string>
    <key>Tracks</key>
    <dict>
      <key>0</key>
      <dict>
        <key>Track ID</key><integer>0</integer>
        <key>Name</key><string>American Idol 2013</string>
        <key>Artist</key><string>Amber Holcomb</string>
        <key>Album Artist</key><string>Amber Holcomb</string>
        <key>Album</key><string>Unknown Album</string>
        <key>Kind</key><string>MPEG audio file</string>
        <key>Size</key><integer>3645</integer>
        <key>Total Time</key><integer>233000</integer>
        <key>Date Modified</key><date>Thu Mar 14 12:11:12 2013</date>
        <key>Date Added</key><date>Thu Apr 04 16:10:15 2013</date>
        <key>Bitrate</key><integer>128</integer>
        <key>Location</key><string>file://localhost/Z:%5Canthony%5CMusic%5CiTunes%5CiTunes%20Media%5CMusic%5CUnknown%20Artist%5CUnknown%20Album%5CAmber%20Holcomb%20-%20A%20Moment%20Like%20This%20-%20Studio%20Version%20-%20American%20Idol%202013.mp3</string>
        <key>File Folder Count</key><integer>-1</integer>
        <key>Library Folder Count</key><integer>-1</integer>
      </dict>
```

and here's what I got for my code so far:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file(base_url().'uploads/xmlbackup2.xml');
        $varKey = $xml->dict[0]->dict[0]->dict[0]->children();

        $keyName ="";
        $valName ="";



foreach($xml->dict[0]->dict[0]->dict as $dict1){

            foreach($dict1->children() as $dictChild){

                if($dictChild->getName() == "key"){
                    $keyName = $dictChild;
                } else {
                    $valName = $dictChild;
                }



            }

        }
```

I've tried a few things like creating two arrays and try to merge them...but it just fails for me, most likely I have the code incorrectly done.

Essentially what I'm going to do after the 2nd `foreach` loop completes is to drop the data into SQL. However I need to create the associative first to make it work in codeigniter.

Comment: Do you use simpleXML ?

Comment: @svetlio - Yes, I updated my code to reflect that. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php#102277 Try this .. it may help you

Comment: @Svetlio - Thanks, I saw that, but I don't know how that would work with the XML I have, its layout is weird looking to me and I don't know how it would associate the values in the KEY tags with the neighboring tags.

For example:
<key>Track ID</key><integer>0</integer>
<key>Name</key><string>blah</string>
Track ID => 0
Name => blah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this something like what you are looking for?

```
$myArray = Array();
$currentKey;    
foreach($xml->dict[0] as $dict1){
    foreach($dict1->children() as $dictChild){
        if($dictChild->getName() == "key"){
            $currentKey = $dictChild;
        } else {
            $myArray[(string)$currentKey] = (string)$dictChild;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I tested out the code and I was getting the warning that you were getting. Casting to strings seems to fix that. Below is the example file I made and the output I am getting.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$myArray = Array();
$currentKey;

$xml;
if (file_exists('test.xml'))
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');

foreach($xml->dict[0] as $dict1){
    foreach($dict1->children() as $dictChild){
        if($dictChild->getName() == "key"){
            $currentKey = $dictChild;
        } else {
            $myArray[(string)$currentKey] = (string)$dictChild;
        }
    }
}

print '<pre>';
print_r($myArray);
print '</pre>';

?>

Array
(
    [Track ID] => 0
    [Name] => American Idol 2013
    [Artist] => Amber Holcomb
    [Album Artist] => Amber Holcomb
    [Album] => Unknown Album
    [Kind] => MPEG audio file
    [Size] => 3645
    [Total Time] => 233000
    [Date Modified] => Thu Mar 14 12:11:12 2013
    [Date Added] => Thu Apr 04 16:10:15 2013
    [Bitrate] => 128
    [Location] => file://localhost/Z:%5Canthony%5CMusic%5CiTunes%5CiTunes%20Media%5CMusic%5CUnknown%20Artist%5CUnknown%20Album%5CAmber%20Holcomb%20-%20A%20Moment%20Like%20This%20-%20Studio%20Version%20-%20American%20Idol%202013.mp3
    [File Folder Count] => -1
    [Library Folder Count] => -1
)
```

Comment: Maybe this is it. Trying it now...brb

Comment: So I tried this, and I get: 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Illegal offset type

Filename: controllers/xml.php

Line Number: 22

--------

Line Number 22 is pointing to the $myArray[$currentKey] = $dictChild;

Comment: YUP YUP! Thank you very much for your help, that so worked! I tried this before, but never tried (string). thanks again! :)